# How to resize a jpg in a UIImageView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I loaded a jpg into a UIImageView.  The image is oversized to the iPhone screen.  How can I resize it to a specific CGRect frame?

```
UIImageView *uivSplash = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iPhone-Splash.jpg"]];
[self.view addSubview:uivSplash];
```

Comment: check the related box on the right: this question is answered 100s of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UIImageView` is just a `UIView`, so you can change its `frame` property.

```
uivSplash.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want a method like the following:

```
CGFloat newWidth    = whateverYourDesiredWidth; // someView.size.width for example
CGFloat newHeight   = whateverYourDesiredHeight; // someView.size.height for example

CGSize newSize      = CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);

[yourLargeImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)];
UIImage * newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


return newImage;
```

So this is getting your desired width and height (maybe the screen size, maybe hard-coded size, maybe a size based on a UIView) and re-drawing the image in a context that is that size.

~Good Luck

EDIT: it occurs to me I may have misunderstood your desire, so I'll also point out (as others have said) that UIImageView has properties for its image that let you fit it to size, scale to fill, retain aspect ratio, etc.